# 2 ESP32's GPIOs to same header pins isolation

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, gpio, isolation

Hey all I am wondering if my idea below would work.

What I am wanting to do is connect 2 (really 3 ESP32's and 4 ATmega32u4's) micro controllers (in the example there are just 2 ESP32's for simplicity) and they both connect to the same header pins.

[image]

I know that this would not work if both ESP32's were powered on but would this work if only 1 of the ESP32 were to be powered while the other has no power?

I was unsure if this type of setup would cause an issue with one another? Or if this setup is fine as long as one is turned off?

If this would not work what could you suggest I can use in order to isolate the 2 ESP32's from each other? I was thinking a multiplexer but that would just allow 1 GPIO pin to then have 16 more GPIO pins for it.

I was also thinking about some type of reply but that would be a lot of relays to since the ESP32 has 25+ GPIO pins that I would connect to the headers.

There was another thought of using some type of optocoupler but like the suggestion above, this would also have many of them for the 25+ GPIOs.

Suggestions or confirmation would be great! Perhaps a IC that I have not heard of before that would be a good fit for this? Don't want to blow either up :)

Disclaimer: Also posted on

[eevblog.com](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/2-esp32s-gpios-to-same-header-pins-isolation/?action=post;msg=4773293)

[electro-tech-online.com](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/2-esp32s-gpios-to-same-header-pins-isolation.164698)

[allaboutcircuits.com](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/2-esp32s-gpios-to-same-header-pins-isolation.192696)

Comment: There's probably some ways to do it, but this seems like a weird design. What is it for? You need 7 different programs and can't merge them into one?

Comment: Thanks for the input @user253751

Comment: I asked because there might be an easier way to do whatever you are  trying to do